# Como pasar dos parametros a un controller via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, revisión-de-código

estoy trabajando en un proyecto ASP Mvc, tengo el siguiente controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Asociar(int? id, int proveedorId)
{

    return PartialView("Companies");
}
```

En mi vista le paso estos parámetros de la siguiente manera:

```
<a class='asociar' style='color: #004881' href='/administrador/asociar/@item.CompañiaId' id='@item.CompañiaId' title='Asociar al Proveedor'>
```

Este es mi Ajax.

```
    $('.asociar').click(function () {
    var proveedorId = $("#proveedorId");
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "post",
        data: proveedorId,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                //Refresh
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

## proveedorId es un elemento oculto.

Actualmente me están llegando ambos valores al Controller, pero quisiera saber si es la manera mas optima para realizar esto, o si estoy cometiendo algún error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al invocar el action del controller puedes usar json para enviar datos

```
$('.asociar').click(function () {

    var params = {
        id: ..., //aqui defines el valor del parametro
        proveedorId: $("#proveedorId").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "post",
        data: params,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                //Refresh
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

En realidad `model binding` de asp.net mvc esta tomando el `id` porque lo defines como parte del route cuando en el codigo seguro tienes algo como esto:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
);
```

Al usar `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` en el ultimo parametro de forma opcional esta el id que recibes en el action.

Pero seria bueno si puedes enviarlo de uan forma unificada y controlada usando json.

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro.

Answer (score 4):

usa un objeto de js:

```
$('.asociar').click(function () {
    var proveedorId = $("#proveedorId");
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "post",
        data: { id: algunaId, proveedorId : provId } ,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                //Refresh
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lamentablemente solo puedo marcar una respuesta.